# Why is my LWJGL alpha_anti_aliasing not working?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, alpha, antialiasing

I just wrote some code with LWJGL and when I start my program now, it just outputs a square with rounded edges (The round edges are created in a shader, not by a texture). This square has a lot of aliasing around those edges and I would like to remove it. I believe, the common way to do this in LWJGL is just to add `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 8);` to the window hints and then call `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);`. The edges are rounded because of their alpha values (not because they have multiple vertices), I also have to call `glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE)` in order to enable OpenGL alpha Anti-Aliasing. But for some reason this does not work, only the alpha blending is fine but the alpha AA is not activated. This is the window creation code:

```
private void init() {
    GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
    if (!glfwInit())
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

    glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 8);
    
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, GLFW_TRUE);
    
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height,title,NULL,NULL);
    
    if(window == NULL) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
    }
    
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window,key,scancode,action,mods) -> {
        keyPress(window,key,scancode,action,mods);
    });
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, (window,xPos,yPos) -> {
        mousePos(window,xPos,yPos);
    });
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, (window,button,action,mods) -> {
        mouseClick(window,button,action,mods);
    });
    
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, (window, width, height) -> {
        glViewport(0, 0,width, height);
    });
    
    try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
        IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1);
        IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1);
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);
        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(
                window,
                (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
        );
    }
    
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glfwShowWindow(window);
    GL.createCapabilities();
    
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);  
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE); 

    
    try {
        initCallback.invoke(this);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        System.err.println("Incompatible Method for initCallback");
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a idea why this is not working?

Answer (score -2):

Turn on AA in your GPU's control panel.

[image]

AA OFF:
[image]

AA ON:
[image]

EDIT: OP said they have an AMD card. [Here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/dh-012#faq-Anti-Aliasing-Method)
EDIT 2: Corrected the answer and added images.

P.S. `window.samples` is the wrapper code I wrote and use for GLFW/LWJGL 3.2.

Comment: I don't have a nvida card and i don't know if there even is this option in the amd software. I'm really not a pro when it comes to antialiasing and this could be wrong, but i believe that the anti aliasing i want to enable uses MSAA and not FXAA so maby this setting wouldn't even change it.

Comment: This is an SS from my machine I couldn't possibly have predicted what GPU you had. With that out of the way, AMD cards used to have AMD Catalyst, I don't know what they have right now but you must have some sort of control panel if you installed your drivers correctly. Look up the settings in your control panel and enable AA there.

Comment: i found the option and enabled it, but nothing has changed. i will try restarting my computer. Btw my reputation is too low to downvote anyone just in case you thought i downvoted your answer

Comment: @MarkBlace My previous answer was wrong. Please see the edit.

Comment: @Rabbid76 did you try it out with the settings I've shown? If you did how can you explain the behaviour in my answer?